# Building service worker file via webpack

Tags: webpack, service-worker

My webpack config looks pretty much like this -

```
  entry: {
    main: './src/lib/bootstrap.ts',
    sw: './src/sw/sw-bootstrap.ts'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js'
  }
```

In my case I would like the `sw-bootstrap` to not have the `chunkhash` appended to it.

Comment: Can you define two separate configs within an array and adjust it per entry there?

Comment: Wow! yes, now i feel so dumb :(

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the `CommonChunksPlugin` of Webpack in combination with entries:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/lib/bootstrap.ts',
    sw: './src/sw/sw-bootstrap.ts'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'sw',
      chunks: ['sw'], // Use here the same keys as under "entry"
      filename: '[name].js'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js'
  }
};
```